# Java Android Sensor Co2

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

Is there a way on how to get CO2 from an Android Mobile using in-build sensors. Currently what I have obtained is the Current Speed, the Air Pressure, the Humidity and the Noise Amplitude by using the Environment Sensor.

If this is not possible, is there a way that I can calculate the CO2 (the value can be an estimate one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently no built-in sensors that can measure co2 levels.

I am not aware of any way to calculate this.

There are 3rd party external sensors that do what you want, but again - not built-in the phone.

Comment: ok thanks.. Is there any other way around to calculate the co2 levels without any external sensors. I am asking this, because I am developing an app to push co2 emissions to the cloud.

Comment: I do not deal with this field, but I do not think there is any way to calculate this without a proper sensor.. sorry...

Comment: @keithSpiteri: "Is there any other way around to calculate the co2 levels without any external sensors" -- no.